# How to start Boot2Docker in PowerShell in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, boot2docker

Windows 7/8 has a more advanced command-prompt called PowerShell. This has easy copy paste and scrolling support. Boot2Docker is a simple application for Windows to launch a Docker environment.

Problem is: the Docker environment is launched on the old command prompt, and no advanced options are available. Is there any small technique where we can use PowerShell + Boot2Docker?

**Edit**: You can refer the latest document reference from Docker. They gave simple guidelines to access Docker shell from Putty and Powershell.

https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem in few steps. There can be better solutions as well.

Boot2Docker uses Git shell to launch virtual machine for Virtualbox.

**Step 1:** Append following to your System PATH (Environment Variables)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;

**Step 2:** Open Powershell (Run+powershell)

**Step 3:** Go to your Docker installation folder in powershell and execute following command

sh.exe .\start.sh

[image]

Please find out simple shortcut approach to avoid hard copy.